# Can anybody inform me about how to use log4j.properties ouside war file?

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to log4j. I have a servlet `Log4jInit` which loads on start up.

```
public class Log4jInit extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        System.out.println("Log4J for entities initializing");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String log4jLocation = context.getInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jLocation);
    }
}
```

And I have declared my `web.xml` as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>com.zeomega.jiva_product_entities</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.zeomega.jiva_product_entities.Log4jInit</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>${HOME}/Log4J/log4j.properties</param-value> 
</context-param>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>standard-real-time</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But it throws error saying logger is not initialized in the Java class where I am using. My guess is it is not picking up the `log4j.properties` file path. Can anybody help me know how to import the log4j file outside war?

I am facing below error while running appliccation:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.zeomega.jiva_product_entities.JivaProductEntity).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info
```

Comment: As a note, if you're just starting out, it's probably better to go with slf4j if you have the option. It's a redesign by the original author of log4j with a lot more flexibility and better performance, and you can integrate with existing code that uses log4j.

Comment: I cant do that, As it is existing application where i have to make changes

Comment: Is it LOG4J version 1 or 2?

Comment: @LeosLiterak its version 1

Comment: When is this warning fired? Can you find out if it is before or after your Log4jInit is run?

Comment: It is fired before Log4jInit. Can there be anything wrong with my build.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following procedure copied from [LOG4J 1.2 website](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html):

> 1. Set the resource string variable to the value of the log4j.configuration system property. The preferred way to specify the
>      default initialization file is through the log4j.configuration system
>      property. In case the system property log4j.configuration is not
>      defined, then set the string variable resource to its default value
>      "log4j.properties".
> 2. Attempt to convert the resource variable to a URL.
> 3. If the resource variable cannot be converted to a URL, for example due to a MalformedURLException, then search for the resource from the
>      classpath by calling
>      org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.getResource(resource, Logger.class)
>      which returns a URL. Note that the string "log4j.properties"
>      constitutes a malformed URL.

E.g. for tomcat:

```
export TOMCAT_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=foobar.txt"
```

Where `foobar.txt` is a path to configuration file.

Comment: Well, you should rephrase your question. It is currently "Can anybody help me know how to import the log4j file outside war?". And show the error as well.